# Can you make a recharging Tattoo Spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items, feats

Is it possible to make a [spell tattoo](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/tattoo-spell) from the [Craft Spell Tattoo feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/rite-publishing/item-creation-feats---3rd-party---rite-publishing/craft-spell-tattoo-item-creation) that is permanently reusable? That is, a tattoo that recharges and can be cast (e.g.) 1/day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Custom Magic Item Creation

Following [Magic Item Creation Rules](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html), this would be pretty simple and straight forward.

### How I Would Do It (Opinion)

Let's break it down.

Base Cost: From the first entry under Spell Effect (Command word), we can see that the base cost should be Spell level x Caster level x 1,800 gp.

Modifications: For a tattoo like the one you mentioned, it would be a slot-less item, which adds the "No Space Limitation" modification, which doubles the price. And, as you suggested, using X times per day, you divide by (5/X), where the higher value for X results in a higher price. This second modification is taken from the "Charges Per Day" row under Special.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for, I was having a hard time finding it and understanding it.

Comment: No problem. To my knowledge, there's nothing about Magic Item Creation that would prevent you from making a tattoo, though you'd probably still need the Craft Spell Tattoo feat.